# Is HTML 5 a superset of HTML 4.01 Transitional?

Tags: html, cross-browser, standards, doctype

We have a PHP framework which was originally written in 2005, and consequently the default DOCTYPE is `HTML 4.01 Transitional`.

Whilst this can be overridden, most projects (even recent ones) have not changed the default, and so most projects will be serving documents as HTML 4.

All HTML generated by the framework has been designed to pass the W3C HTML 4 Validator, and most projects will also be generating valid HTML as this is a company requirement (though exceptions are allowed where necessary, e.g. use of some new HTML elements like `<canvas>` which would fail the HTML 4 validation but which browsers all nevertheless handle correctly).

**My question:** If I simply switch the framework to use a modern DOCTYPE will the HTML 4 mark-up validate correctly as HTML 5, or will I also need to make changes to the code?

**A secondary question:** Will rendering or browser support be affected by this change?

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) article correctly then all browsers will be going from Quirks mode to Standards mode. This means that browser rendering is likely to be affected.

I don't know about the validation, but since rendering will be affected it is a safe bet to assume the validation will as well.

Interesting reading:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode
- https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/

Comment: Good point!  We include a system identifier (`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`), so from the table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types it looks like the pages will be in 'almost standards mode' in nearly all browsers.  That may introduce minor rendering changes, but not nearly as big as if it was going from Quirk to Standard mode.

Comment: Having said that, the Page Info box in Firefox says the pages are 'Standards compliance mode', which contradicts the Wikipedia article (unless Firefox doesn't distinguish between standards and almost standards in that dialog box).

Comment: Often, standards mode and almost standards mode are not distinguished. But it's easy to tell which is being used. Add this to your html `<div style="float:left;background:yellow"><img src="http://placehold.it/100"></div>` If it shows a yellow stripe under the grey box, standards mode is being used. If there's no yellow stripe, almost standards mode is in use.

Comment: The yellow stripe is not visible, and changing to an HTML 5 doctype makes it appear.  In both cases Firefox reports "Standards compliant mode", so you're right - it doesn't distinguish between Standards and Almost Standards.